# Store (UniqueString, String) in java

Tags: java, hashmap, set

To store a pair of values with only one value as unique.

Input:
add(String, String)

```
49.205.119.239, hello
14.192.212.57, yollo
49.205.119.239, tello
14.192.212.57, bella
```

Expected Output:

```
49.205.119.239, hello
14.192.212.57, yollo
```

I tried the below code. The`uniqueIp.putIfAbsent(line, actualLine);` takes all the values even repeated keys (line).

```
public static void processLine(String actualLine) throws IOException {
  GetLocationExample obj = new GetLocationExample();
  Map<String, String> uniqueIp = new HashMap<String, String>();
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([(]100.0)[)][\\]][:]*");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(actualLine);
  String ip = null;
  String line = null ;
  if (matcher.find())
  {
       ip= "100%";
       Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b");
      Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(actualLine);

      if (matcher1.find())
      { line= (matcher1.group(0));
        uniqueIp.putIfAbsent(line, actualLine);  
      }

      else { System.out.println("Not Present"); }
  }
  else { return; }

  for (String name: uniqueIp.keySet())
  { 
      String key =name.toString();
      String value = uniqueIp.get(name).toString();  
      System.out.println(key + " " + value);  
  }
```

Tried `if(!uniqueIp.containsKey(key))`. Did not work

Comment: key of your hashmap is `Set`, you're trying to save `String`, what do you expect?

Comment: use HashMap<String, Set<String>> instead

Comment: Well... 'line' is not initialized in the above example code and is null.. would also throw an error.

Comment: So, if you encounter a second 'a1' then you don't want to update the value , since you already have a stored 'a1' value?

Comment: There is nothing in your question that says you don't want `a1, tello` and `b1, bella` or `a1, hello` and `b1, bella` as output... Did you mean to say you only want the first occurrence of each key?

Comment: I get "The method put(String, Set<String>) in the type HashMap<String,Set<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"

Comment: Yes, unique keys are to be stored while I add all the repeated keys to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of guarding with a call to `containsKey()` as everyone suggests, simply use the [`putIfAbsent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) method:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.putIfAbsent("a1", "hello");
map.putIfAbsent("b1", "yollo");
map.putIfAbsent("a1", "tello");
map.putIfAbsent("b1", "bella");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you implement Apache Ant-like logic: the property is constant if once set, further changes have no effect (once a1="hello", setting "tello" later does not matter).

Then simple:

```
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

...

```
  if (!map.containsKey(key)) 
    map.put(key, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of your `uniqueIp` Map from

```
HashMap<Set<String>,String>
```

to

```
HashMap<String,String>
```

Furthermore, I assume you don't want to update a value if the key is already in your map.

If so, you have to check if the map already contains the key before putting a new key value pair into your map.

```
if(!uniqueMap.contains(key)) {
     uniqueMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, you are trying to only set the value of a key once and after that the value for a key should not be updated. Therefore, you can accomplish this with a simple `Map<String,String>`.

Here is a complete code sample showing your input and expected output:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestUniqueStrings {
    Map<String, String> storage = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Attempts to add a unique value under key.
     * @param key
     * @param value
     * @return True if the key did not exist
     */
    boolean add(String key, String value){
        if(!storage.containsKey(key)){
            storage.put(key, value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void printStorage(){
        System.out.println("Contents of storage:\n" + storage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestUniqueStrings tus = new TestUniqueStrings();
        tus.add("a1", "hello");
        tus.add("b1", "yollo");
        tus.add("a1", "tello");
        tus.add("b1", "bella");

        tus.printStorage();
    }
}
```